# Call a function after state changes

Tags: react-native

I'm building a React Native app and when one button is pressed I want to call two functions. The first one will make a get call and set the state `loading: true`, the second one will show a popup with the result of that get call.

I am calling the second function only if `loading === false` but it is executed immediately after the first one before the state can change, because loading is false by default. I can resolve this with `setTimeout` but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do this.

```
onPress() {
  this.props.getUsers();
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (this.props.loading === false) {
      this.props.popUpVisible();
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create callback function for that

```
getUsers = (callback) => {
  //do whatever you want

  //when it's done
  callback();
}
```

In onPress function

```
onPress = () => {
  this.props.getUsers(() => {
    if (this.props.loading === false) {
      this.props.popUpVisible();
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**setState** Function can take two param:

setState(updater, callback)

```
setState({loading:true},() => { 
     //this fires once state.loading === true

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use getDerivedStateFromProps. It always fire when component's props change.
Below is the example.

```
class EmailInput extends Component {
  state = {
    email: this.props.defaultEmail,
    prevPropsUserID: this.props.userID
  };

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    // Any time the current user changes,
    // Reset any parts of state that are tied to that user.
    // In this simple example, that's just the email.
    if (props.userID !== state.prevPropsUserID) {
      return {
        prevPropsUserID: props.userID,
        email: props.defaultEmail
      };
    }
    return null;
  }

  // ...
}
```